# User login issue in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am working on a project whose home page contains a login form that asks the user to insert the email and the password and then -if authenticated- the user navigates to the profile page. And, here is the part of code that I am implementing the private route in React :

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: `${baseURL}/`, state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

The thing is, in case I put the link of the home page even if I were logged in, it navigates to the home page and asks me to enter the email and password again. I want to do something that redirect the user to the profile page if he inserted the link of the homepage while his token is still valid and not expired. How is it done? any help?

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: You have done right by checking localStorage. Check what is token value when you insert link. If your token is removed that's why it should prompt you to add email and password

Comment: @ShubhamVerma it still appears there and when I navigate back to the profile link, it navigates even when I don't enter the email and the password.

Comment: Can you add your code here: http://react.new/

Answer (score 0):

you also need a localStorage checker on your homepage.

```
useEffect(() => {
   
      /*back to profile if the user attempt to go to home page even the user was currently logged-in*/
     
     const isUserLogged = localStorage.getItem('user');
     if (isUserLogged) {
          return props.history.push(`/profile`);
     }
 }, []);
```

Comment: Still the same problem. When I insert the link of my login page even when there is a valid token, it navigates to it anyways.

Comment: try to place a console.log inside the if statement before return statement. if no message then the localStorage is falsy that's why its not redirected on the profile page.